# Downloading completed DocuSign documents in bulk

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the new experience for DocuSign and a PowerForm.  I received many signed documents. Each document has custom fields associated with it.  I now would like to download all the PDF documents and populated custom fields to my local system.

I figured out how to export the document data, but I can't figure out how to export the PDF documents in bulk, as well as matching them to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the REST API. Some (older) recipes for downloading documents are at https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/get-an-envelopes-document-list

Using the NodeJS SDK you could look at https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/node-sdk/download_documents/download_documents.js 
or for PHP: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/php-sdk/download_documents/download_documents.php

Comment: This looks good.  Any idea on how to get a production integrator key?  Do I really need to create 20 docs in dev and run this script 20 times so I can get a production key?